# Setuptools: How to make sure file generated by packed code be deleted by pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, pip

I have a simple code named `main.py` that generates a folder and a file within it:

```
import os
def main():
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'folder')

    if not os.path.isdir(path):
        os.mkdir(path)

    with open(os.path.join(path, 'file.txt'), 'w+') as f:
        f.write('something')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

If this script run in a folder, then the structure should be like:

```
.
├── main.py
└── folder
    └── file.txt
```

---

I use a `setup.py` file to pack the code up, where I assigned an entry point named `foo`. The `setup.py` looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup  
setup(
    name='mypack',
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': ['foo=mypack.main:main'],
    },
    packages=['mypack'],
    package_data={'': '*.txt'},
    include_package_data=True
)
```

I packed the code with the structure below:

```
.
├── mypack
│   └── main.py
└── setup.py
```

And I install it by `pip install .` in the root directory. Then I run `foo`, it indeed generated a folder and a file. Then I uninstall it by `pip uninstall mypack`, the output in the terminal shows :

```
Uninstalling mypack-0.0.0:
  Would remove:
    d:\programdata\envs\testsetup\lib\site-packages\mypack-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
    d:\programdata\envs\testsetup\lib\site-packages\mypack\main.py
    d:\programdata\envs\testsetup\scripts\foo-script.py
    d:\programdata\envs\testsetup\scripts\foo.exe
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled mypack-0.0.0
```

The `folder\file.txt` didn't deleted by `pip uninstall`, also the output of it didn't mention anything about `folder\file.txt`

---

Then I pack the code with the structure below:

```
.
├── mypack
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── main.py
└── setup.py
```

Where the `__init__.py` was an empty file. I did the same procedure, that is: `pip install .` -> `foo` -> `pip uninstall mypack`, then the output in the terminal is:

```
Uninstalling mypack-0.0.0:
  Would remove:
    d:\programdata\envs\testsetup\lib\site-packages\mypack-0.0.0-py3.6.egg-info
    d:\programdata\envs\testsetup\lib\site-packages\mypack\*
    d:\programdata\envs\testsetup\scripts\foo-script.py
    d:\programdata\envs\testsetup\scripts\foo.exe
  Would not remove (might be manually added):
    d:\programdata\envs\testsetup\lib\site-packages\mypack\folder\file.txt
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled mypack-0.0.0
```

This time, `folder\file.txt` was mentioned in the output of `pip uninstall`, but was not automatically removed by `pip`.

---

**So my questions:**

- **Why there is a difference between with and without `__init__.py`**
- **Is there any method that can make `pip` automatically remove `folder\file.txt` like that in my example?**

Comment: It's quite unusual for packages to write to files inside its installdir. Imagine `root` installed the package, but `sean` tries to execute it. You will fail because of a permission denied error. It would be much wiser to work in the current working dir, or in a config directory in the user's homedir. Can you elaborate more why you need to create this file in the installdir?

Comment: @NilsWerner I just wanna investigate the behavior of generating additional code during python runtime. I guess this practice would be practical for programs that generate log files.

Comment: Generate the logfiles somewhere else then, your current workdir for example ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `__init__.py` file tells python that the directory it is in is a module, and to look at all the sub-modules located within. This makes `pip` think that it is a module, therefore mentioning everything inside it.

From the documentation:

> The **init**.py files are required to make Python treat the directories as containing packages; this is done to prevent directories with a common name, such as string, from unintentionally hiding valid modules that occur later (deeper) on the module search path. In the simplest case, **init**.py can just be an empty file

For your second question, my answer is *maybe*. I say this because, there is no way *I* know for sure that this is possible.

**P.S:** I don't know for sure(because I have not tested it), but maybe you could change `file.txt`'s extension to `.py` maybe fooling pip into removing that.

Comment: Thanks for your reminder. I tried rename `file.txt` into `file.py`, it still not deleted by `pip`. Even if I modified the `main.py` code to generate an additional `__init__.py` inside the `folder` directory, it's still not working.

Answer (score 2):

At line 381 of [pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/master/src/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py):

```
if not verbose:
            will_remove, will_skip = compress_for_output_listing(self.paths)
        else:
            # In verbose mode, display all the files that are going to be
            # deleted.
            will_remove = list(self.paths)
            will_skip = set()

        _display('Would remove:', will_remove)
        _display('Would not remove (might be manually added):', will_skip)
        _display('Would not remove (outside of prefix):', self._refuse)
```

You can see `compress_for_output_listing` seperating files to be deleted from files to keep, except if `verbose` is `True`, it seems to delete them all. It's a bummer though, since `verbose` seems to be an internal function argument, and there is no command-line argument to set it, and would require changes to the source code for it to delete all files instead.

Comment: You are right. Seems that `pip` is designed not deleting files that generated during runtime. 
The word `Would not remove (might be manually added)` in the source code implies this design manner.

Comment: its done to preserve package extensions installed, as they r basically separate packages installed to shared directory namespace